# minGW error on locale library

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw, mingw32

I changed from using Dev-c++ to visual studio code. But it seems i can't compile the minGW because of this bug, i got this bug if i use sublime too. Please help me with this.
*sorry for my bad english

> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\locale.h:36:13: warning: #pragma system_header ignored outside include file
>    #pragma GCC system_header
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c++locale.h:41:0,
>                    from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\localefwd.h:40,
>                    from C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\locale.h:38:
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\clocale:53:11: error: '::lconv' has not been declared
>      using ::lconv;
>              ^~~~~
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\clocale:54:11: error: '::setlocale' has not been declared
>      using ::setlocale;
>              ^~~~~~~~~
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\clocale:55:11: error: '::localeconv' has not been declared
>      using ::localeconv;
>              ^~~~~~~~~~
>   In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\localefwd.h:40:0,
>                    from C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\locale.h:38:
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c++locale.h: In function 'int std::__convert_from_v(int* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)':
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c++locale.h:60:19: error: 'setlocale' is not a member of 'std'
>        char* __old = std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 0);
>                      ^~~
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c++locale.h:60:34: error: 'LC_NUMERIC' was not declared in this scope
>        char* __old = std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 0);
>                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c++locale.h:67:2: error: 'setlocale' is not a member of 'std'
>     std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
>     ^~~
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c++locale.h:83:2: error: 'setlocale' is not a member of 'std'
>     std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, __sav);
>     ^~~